# What is the distribution of the number of inversions in a riffle shuffle with fixed cut?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, card-games

Fix $a,b \ge 1$. Starting with a deck of $a+b$ distinct cards in order, consider cutting the deck into the first $a$ cards (collectively $A$) and the last $b$ cards (collectively $B$), and then riffling the two decks together (ie, merging them while preserving the order of each deck). There are ${a+b \choose a,b}$ possible outcomes. Each outcome has a number of inversions. When selecting an outcome uniformly at random, what is the distribution of the number of inversions?

Here are a couple equivalent formulations of this:

- Form a grid graph with $a$ vertical steps and $b$ horizontal steps, with all edges having unit length and oriented down or right. The riffles are naturally in bijection with the paths from the top left to the bottom right: whenever the $i$-th step goes down, the $i$-th card in the riffle comes from $A$, and whenever the $i$-th step goes right, the $i$-th card comes from $B$. The number of inversions appears as the *area* below this path. So this question is, equivalently, what is the distribution of the area below a uniformly random path in the grid?
- Select, uniformly at random, non-negative integers $\lambda_0,\ldots,\lambda_b$ subject to $\lambda_0+\cdots+\lambda_b = a$, and output $\sum_{i=0}^b i\cdot \lambda_i$. This is distributed the same as above: each choice of $\lambda_0,\ldots,\lambda_b$ corresponds bijectively to a choice of path in the grid interpretation where $\lambda_i$ counts the number of vertical steps following the $i$-th horizontal step. The sum counts, row-by-row, the area below the path. One can of course swap the roles of $a$ and $b$ as well.
- Form the polynomial $$\sum_{d=0}^{ab} c_{a,b,d}\cdot q^d = \binom{a+b}{a}_q$$ in the indeterminate $q$. (See [Gaussian binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient).) Sample the value $d$ with probability $c_{a,b,d}/\binom{a+b}{a}$. (This is a probability distribution.)

In any case, let's call the random variable $V_{a,b}$. It is, of course, integer-valued. Every integer in $[0,ab]$ is a possible outcome. By the 180° rotational symmetry of the grid, the distribution is symmetric about $ab/2$. In particular the mean is $ab/2$. I've computed the variance as $\frac{1}{12}ab(a+b+1)$. That's essentially the limit of what I can prove though. Empirically, the distribution is unimodal, and no outcome is particularly likely (maximum probability of any one outcome bounded by $O(1/{\sqrt{ab(a+b)}})$). In general, it seems to loosely resemble a normal distribution with the same first two moments, even when $a$ and/or $b$ is small. I'd like to understand to what extent that is true.

In case it helps, here are two more tidbits:

- $V_{a,b}$ satisfies a recurrence in the sense that the distribution of $V_{a,b}$ coincides with the distribution where, with probability $\frac{a}{a+b}$, one samples $V_{a-1,b}$, while with probability $\frac{b}{a+b}$, one samples $V_{a,b-1}$ and adds $a$.
- It seems nicer to work with a related quantity, $\delta_{a,b} = ab - 2V_{a,b}$. In the deck-shuffling formulation, it counts $-1$ for each inversion, and $+1$ for each non-inversion. In the grid formulation, it counts the area above the path minus the area below the path. Similarly there is an interpretation in the integer-partition formulation. $\delta_{a,b}$ is integer-valued, and every integer in $[-ab,ab]$ with the same parity as $ab$ is a possible outcome. It has a similar recurrence to $V_{a,b}$ in that $\delta_{a,b}$ coincides with the distribution where, with probability $\frac{a}{a+b}$, one samples $b+\delta_{a-1,b}$, and with probability $\frac{b}{a+b}$ one samples $-a+\delta_{a,b-1}$. $\delta_{a,b}$ is symmetrically distributed about 0 (so all odd-order moments are zero), and its variance is $\frac{1}{3}ab(a+b+1)$. Its fourth moment is $$\frac{1}{15}ab(a+b+1)\cdot[5(a^2b+b^2a) - 2(a^2+b^2) + 3ab - 2(a+b)].$$ I computed the second and fourth moments using the recurrence for $\delta_{a,b}$.

Comment: All I can say is that the distribution is proportional the coefficients of the $q$-binomial coefficient $\binom{a+b}{a}_q$.

Comment: This is the kind of knowledge I came here for—thank you! Based on some additional searching around I've done, unimodality is decidedly nontrivial to prove, and precise answers will be hard to come by. I'll add this intepretation to the question as another alternative in the meantime.